How can I keep track of which function returned which value, with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()?
My code is as follows:
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    length = len(self.seq)
    futures = [None] * length
    results = []
    for i in range(length):
        f,args,kwargs = self.seq[i]
        future = executor.submit(f, *args, **kwargs)
        futures[i] = future

    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(starts):
        results.append(f.result())

I'd like the return values in results to be ordered by the order of the functions they were returned from in self.seq, but my code orders them in the order of whichever returns first. How can I do this?
For clarification, .as_completed() is not what I'm looking for.  I want to maintain the order of the original function list.

This question is similar to: Python's `concurrent.futures`: Iterate on futures according to order of completion. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm looking for a way to maintain the order of my original list. The .as_completed() method orders by order of completion and is not what I want.

The simplest answer is to pass a counter argument along with the rest of your args and kwargs, where you set counter to be i.  You then need to modify f to return the counter along with whatever other values its supposed to return.  Your results can then be sorted by the counter.
Alternatively, create a results array of the right size, and as each result comes back, the counter value tells you where to put it in the array.

If you do not have access to f, then just write a wrapper around it:
def f_wrapper(*args, *, counter, **kwargs):
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
    return counter, result

Likewise, you'll write
future = executor.submit(f_wrapper, *args, **kwargs | dict(counter=i))


This class does not have access to the function body of f.  Would passing f, its args and kwargs, and the counter to a helper function do it properly?

See update to my answer.

I'd create dictionary where keys are futures and values are results from futures. Dictionaries in Python are keeping order of creation so you can leverage that:
import concurrent.futures
import time


def f1(i, t):
    time.sleep(t)
    print("f1", i, "done")
    return f"f1({i}, {t})"


def f2(i, t):
    time.sleep(t)
    print("f2", i, "done")
    return f"f2({i}, {t})"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        seq = [(f1, (2,)), (f1, (3,)), (f2, (1,))]

        res, fs = {}, set()
        for i, (f, args) in enumerate(seq):
            future = executor.submit(f, i, *args)
            fs.add(future)
            res[future] = None

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(fs):
            res[f] = f.result()

    print(list(res.values()))

This prints:
f2 2 done
f1 0 done
f1 1 done
['f1(0, 2)', 'f1(1, 3)', 'f2(2, 1)']


wait for the futures, then iterate over them in the same order to get the results:
import concurrent.futures
from operator import add


def fun(a, b, *, op):
    return f"{op.__name__}({a!r}, {b!r}) = {op(a, b)}"


def main():
    seq = [(fun, (x, 20), {"op": add}) for x in range(10)]
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(f, *args, **kwargs) for f, args, kwargs in seq]
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures, return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
        results = [f.result() for f in futures]
        print(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

prints out
[
    "add(0, 20) = 20",
    "add(1, 20) = 21",
    "add(2, 20) = 22",
    "add(3, 20) = 23",
    "add(4, 20) = 24",
    "add(5, 20) = 25",
    "add(6, 20) = 26",
    "add(7, 20) = 27",
    "add(8, 20) = 28",
    "add(9, 20) = 29",
]

